# Assign Time Group to range of times in excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I need help assigning a group to specific times based on hour and day of the week.

So far I have

```
=LOOKUP(HOUR(C2),{0,2,6,16,18,23},{"LATENIGHT","OVERNIGHT","DAYTIME","FRINGE","PRIME","FRINGE"})
```

which is doing the job for Monday to Friday.

On weekends however I need

`=LOOKUP(HOUR(C2),{0,2,6,18},{"LATENIGHT","OVERNIGHT","WEEKEND","PRIME"})`

and I have no idea how to include an `OR` statement.

I have my days of the week on `B2` using `=TEXT(A2,"dddd")` to reference my date column.

Data sample:

```
 - May 22, 2020  Friday     6:45:56 AM  DAYTIME
 - May 22, 2020  Friday     4:15:56 PM  FRINGE
 - May 23, 2020  Saturday  10:15:56 AM  DAYTIME   (should be WEEKEND)
 - May 24, 2020  Sunday    12:15:56 PM  DAYTIME   (should be WEEKEND)
 - May 25, 2020  Monday    12:21:18 AM  LATENIGHT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(
  WEEKDAY(C2,3)>4,
  LOOKUP(
    HOUR(C2),
    {0,2,6,18},
    {"LATENIGHT","OVERNIGHT","WEEKEND","PRIME"}
  ),
  LOOKUP(
    HOUR(C2),
    {0,2,6,16,18,23},
    {"LATENIGHT","OVERNIGHT","DAYTIME","FRINGE","PRIME","FRINGE"})
)
```